# How to set the background image full-width

Tags: css, image, background, setting

i want to set the background with full like this image (must responsive)

[image]

but when i applied it look like this and crop the below part.

https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/180176008/test1/index.html

Please somebody help me ?

Comment: use `background-size: cover;`, also, am closing your question as you didn't posted your code here..

Comment: i use html{ background:url(../img/bak.jpg)no-repeat top  fixed; 
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try below example.

**HTML**

```
<body class='imgclass'>
    <b>Test page</b>
</body>
```

**CSS**

```
.imgclass{
    background-size:cover;
    background-image:url("https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/180176008/test1/Home-Page.jpg") ;

}
```

I hope it can help you [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ULLHk/1/)

Comment: i did this but result is same

Answer (score 2):

Try like this:

```
html { 
  background: url(images/bg.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed; 
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
}
```

And read [this arcticle](http://css-tricks.com/perfect-full-page-background-image/)

Comment: i use html{ background:url(../img/bak.jpg)no-repeat top  fixed; 
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;}